# How to boot ARM kernel using QEMU?

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, arm

I am having a hard time booting up an ARM linux kernel with a rootfs using QEMU.
First I tried compiling it myself, then resorted to the debian linux-image-rt-armmp kernel, nothing works.

Here is what I got:

- I created a rootfs using debootstrap onto an ext4 disk image
- I have the linux kernel ready in vmlinuz (for the debian compiled one) / bzImage (self compiled)
- I copied the initrd created by the debootstrap

I tried a couple of QEMU invocation:

- `qemu-system-arm -machine virt -kernel linux-kernel/vmlinuz  -append "root=/dev/sda rootwait console=ttyAMA0" -drive file=./armhf.img,format=raw,index=0,media=disk -cpu cortex-a15 -smp 2 -s -m 1024` < this waits because the disk is never available
- `qemu-system-arm -machine virt -kernel linux-kernel/vmlinuz  -append "root=/dev/ram rootwait console=ttyAMA0" -initrd linux-kernel/initrd.img -cpu cortex-a15 -smp 2 -s -m 1024 -nographic` < this boots into initramfs however it cannot find /dev/ram, or any other disk
- If I specify another `-machine` than `virt` everything goes silent and I cannot see anything
- Various variations of specifying `-drive file=...` using `-sd` / `-hda`. If I leave the kernel to panic (i.e. omitting `rootwait`), I cannot see any dev available, no matter what I specify.

Because I do not see the disk, I was assuming missing drivers.
Why are they not baked into the debian built kernel?
I tried compiling a few things I read across several posts into the custom kernel, though nothing seemed to work. Does anyone know specific CONFIGs I need to enable here?

I also found [this syzkaller guide](https://github.com/google/syzkaller/blob/master/docs/linux/setup_linux-host_qemu-vm_arm-kernel.md) which uses buildroot to create the rootfs. Though I do not see why their guide would be working if the kernel does not even see the disk. Additionally I would rather use debootstrap.
Is me missing the device tree the root of all this `-dtb /linux/arch/arm/boot/dts/vexpress-v2p-ca15-tc1.dtb`?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The missing device tree was indeed a problem. I could not make it work with the debian built kernel, however the custom build kernel works out-of-the-box (`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- vexpress_defconfig`).

Eventually the os will boot up using this (follow the syzkaller guide to get the DTB):

```
    qemu-system-arm \
        -machine vexpress-a15 \
        -kernel linux-6.4.5/arch/arm/boot/zImage \
        -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0 console=ttyAMA0" \
        -sd ./armhf.img \
        -smp 2 \
        -m 1024 \
        -dtb vexpress-v2p-ca15-tc1.dtb \
        -nographic
```